# Objectify - How to get auto generated id of the entity, when Long is used?

Tags: objectify

How to get auto generated id of the entity, when Long is used? I have an entity like below

```
@Entity
public class DailyChallenge {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String title;
}
```

Here id will be auto generated. How can I get this id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id is set on the entity once you save it to objectify.

```
DailyChallenge de = new DailyChallenge();
de.title = "some title";
ObjectifyService.ofy().save().entities(de).now();
System.out.println(de.id);  // This is non null now.
```